# Polymer- can somebody please explain the this.$.foo.bar JavaScript syntax used in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm a relatively new programmer, and very new to Polymer.  I have scoured the docs, but cannot seem to figure out what this syntax means.  Polymer is the first time I have seen the $ selector used as such.  It appears to select the ID, but I'm not entirely sure what is going on here.

Example

```
<polymer-element name="my-component">
  <template>
    <app-globals id="globals"></app-globals>
    <div id="firstname">{{$.globals.firstName}}</div>
    <div id="lastname">{{$.globals.lastName}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ready: function() {
        console.log('Last name: ' + this.$.globals.lastName);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Found it in the documentation...about 3/4 of the way down the API developer guide.  They reference it several times before this, but explain it a bit towards the end of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is just a field that references a Map which contains all elements with an id attribute inside the shadow DOM of the element and allows concise code to access them where `foo` is the id and `bar` an attribute/field of that element.

A common pitfall is, that elements inside a `<template repeat...>` or `<template if...>` are not included because the map is initialized when the Polymer element is initialized and not updated later, but the elements inside these tags are created/removed dynamically at some later point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Still trying to wrap my had around the shadow DOM.